# NullPointerException when trying to draw a polygon

Tags: java

When I'm trying to draw a polygon I get a `NullPointerException`.
This is how I am trying to do it:

```
Roi roi = imp.getRoi();
Polygon p = roi.getPolygon();
Graphics g=null;
g.drawPolygon(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);
```

Please suggest how I can fix this.

Comment: Graphics g=null; leads to a NPE if you call a method on g.

Comment: You should look at some tutorial about drawing in java. A key point is about how you're code will be called and provided a Graphics instance.

Comment: still the same with the g=null

Comment: I'd recommend learning to use a debugger. You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Amen on the tutorial recommendation. You can't guess at this stuff and hope that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the right Graphics object. This should be done in a JComponent's `paintComponent(...)` method, and you should use the Graphics object passed in by the JVM. Either that or draw this in a BufferedImage using a Graphics2D object obtained from it via `createGraphics()`.

Regarding your edit: **yikes!**

This is guaranteed to throw a NPE every time.

```
Bar bar = null
bar.someMethod();
```

Comment: can you give me some tutorial about this? please

Comment: @user1620554: The standard [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) has a  Swing section and in fact a specific section on Performing Custom Painting.

Comment: public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ...
}
i tryed that but i don't know how can i call the paint method in the my main

Comment: @user1620554: this comment just suggests that you're guessing and that you haven't read the tutorial yet. Please stop guessing and read the tutorial. It will explain all and more.